# Laplace transform of sin(at)

Tags: improper-integrals, laplace-transform

Given $f(t)= \sin (at)$ I want to calculate the Laplace transform of $f(t)$.

I have determined by using integration by parts twice, that the answer should be $$F(s)= \frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$$

Now I want to recalculate it by using just that $$\sin (at)= \frac{1}{2i} \left( {e^{ati}-e^{-ati}}\right) $$

So the integral becomes

$$\frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-st}\left( {e^{ati}-e^{-ati}}\right) = $$

$$ \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{t(ai-s)}-e^{-t(ai+s)}dt  =$$

$$ \frac{1}{2i} \left[\frac{1}{ai-s}e^{t(ai-s)} \right]_0^{\infty} +\frac{1}{2i} \left[\frac{1}{ai+s}e^{-t(ai+s)} \right]_0^{\infty} $$

My question now is: How to determine the limit of $e^{t(ai-s)}$ as $t$ goes to $\infty$ ?

Comment: Your answer for the first part should be $\frac{a}{s^2+a^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to handle this is as follows:

In order to proceed, we need to have some more information about $s$; otherwise, we can't be sure that the integral will converge.  So, we assume that $s$ is in the "region of convergence" (ROC) for this function.  In this particular integral, we suppose that $\text{Re} \{s\}>0$, so that $\lim_{t\to\infty}e^{t(-s\pm ai)}=0$.  You should be able to handle the rest.

$$
%\begin{align*}
%\left|\lim_{t\to \infty} e^{t(-s\pm ai)}\right| &=
%\lim_{t\to \infty} \left|e^{t(-s\pm ai)}\right|\\&=
%\lim_{t\to \infty} \left|e^{-st}\right|\cdot\left|e^{\pm ai}\right|\\&=
%\lim_{t\to \infty} \left|e^{-st}\right|\cdot 1=0
%\end{align*}
%$$

Comment: thank you very much. This helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome.  I actually made a little mistake, we say that the **real part** of $s$ is greater than $0$.  $s$ itself might be a complex number.

Comment: I read this now in my book. So this is totally clear now. great :)